# Converting string date to its corresponding day of the week not workin as expected in Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-date

I'm having a bit of problem with a date conversion in JavaScript. I have string in format "2023-12-14" that I would like to convert to its corresponding Day of week in a Vue template( In this instance Thursday). I am using this formula :

```
{{ new Date("2023-12-14").toLocaleString('en-us', {
            timeZone: 'America/New_York',
            weekday: 'long'
        }) }}
```

Unfortunately this is printing out Wednesday instead of Thursday. I figure it has something to do with the UTC but I have included timezone parameter in .toLocaleString but still printing wrong date. It is the same with several other dates I need to convert, they all print out a day earlier then expected. Any help would be much appreciated...

Update Info: My template is

```
{{new Date(gameScores[n -
        1].parameters.date).toLocaleString('en-us', {
            timeZone: 'America/New_York',
            weekday: 'long'
        }) }}
```

Can I output the correct day of week from the template expression?

Comment: The problem is that your Date instance is created *before* the `.toLocaleString()` can be evaluated. It's already before Thursday, because the date string is evaluated as UTC. So it's Thursday in London, but Wednesday in New York.

Comment: Anyway to correct this in the template.

Comment: Well the main problem is, what does "2023-12-14" mean? On planet Earth, it's a whole bunch of different values, because that's the way time works. If you need it to be a particular time on a particular calendar day, with respect to a particular place on earth, you will have to alter that basic date string to stipulate those qualifications.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a functional abstraction to parse the date numerically before using the [`Date()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/Date) constructor. Modify if needed to suit your needs:

```js
function getWeekdayName(dateStr) {
  // Validate input:
  if (!(/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$/).test(dateStr)) {
    throw new Error("Unexpected input format");
  }
  return new Date(
    Number(dateStr.slice(0, 4)),     // year
    Number(dateStr.slice(5, 7)) - 1, // month index
    Number(dateStr.slice(8, 10)),    // day of month
  ).toLocaleString("en-US", { weekday: "long" });
}

const dateStr = "2023-12-14";
const weekdayName = getWeekdayName(dateStr);
console.log(weekdayName);
```

Answer (score 0):

A date in JS is a timestamp under the hood. Since you are not defining a time with that date it defaults to midnight. The locale can then be off by a number of hours, resulting in an unexpected day being returned.

By parsing date from a string, I believe the timezone will default to UTC. The client then makes up for the UTC time difference and can be a day off (since you did not specify a time, it assumes midnight UTC). You can make JS use the local time instead of the default UTC by setting the date with numbers as parameters instead of a string.

So rather than doing:

```
let date = new Date("2023-12-14")
```

You'd do:

```
let date = new Date(2023,11,14) // mind the month
```